# How to exclude Google Analytics traffic with < 1 second visit duration

Tags: google-analytics

I'd like to exclude BOT traffic from Google Analytics reports and it seems that the best way may be to exclude visits that have less than 1 second duration. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few additional things you could do to filter out BOT traffic (and this is a good resource: http://www.analyticsedge.com/2014/12/removing-referral-spam-google-analytics/). But to answer your question, you could set up an advanced segment, where the "Time on page" is set to greater than 60 seconds. Note that you could potentially be filtering out legitimate traffic as well by doing it this way.

Comment: I set up a  segment called "non-bot"  for visitors with sessions > 1 second. Seems to work fine.

Comment: Sessions with no time are the same as bounces, so you can use the built-in segment "Non-bounce Sessions".  BTW all sessions with 1 pageview are zero time -- GA measures time on page ONLY if there is a second page viewed (delta calculation), so all bounces have zero session duration.